# BottomSheetDialogFragment is hidden by soft keyboard, from API 26

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-softkeyboard

[image]
[image]

I have a screen where I use a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` containing an Edit text and save button
By default the BottomSheetDialogFragment was scrolling while soft input is shown so that User can scroll to hit the save button *First Image* & *Second Image*
This was before upgrading from API 25 to API 26
After upgrading the BottomSheetDialogFragment is not scrollable any more.

**Things I tried:**

1. Tried to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and some other options non of them works, I can see that the layout of the activity in the background is adjusted when the keyboard is open but still can't make the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to scroll.
2. Tried to add a scrollview to the fragment in the bottom sheet.